# C array of structs containing pointer to array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

Kind of a complicated one here. I'm trying to simulate a page table and it involves a lot of data structures - specifically I need to create an array of structs that contain pointers to other arrays of structs (since I don't know at definition time how long they need to be). I'm trying to print out the inputs I give it from a file (which I've verified im parsing correctly) and it always gives the wrong output.

As a second question, is there just a better way to do all of this? Keep in mind I need to pass many of these structs into functions later so I figured dynamic memory would be optimal.

```
typedef struct PROCESS {
    int num_vmas;
    int pid;     
    struct VMA *vmalist;
} PROCESS;

typedef struct VMA {
    int start_page;
    int end_page;
    int w_prctd;
    int f_mapped;
} VMA;

PROCESS *pl[num_ps];

for (int i=0; i<num_ps; i++) {
    PROCESS *proc = malloc(sizeof(PROCESS));                // Create individual process

    int num_vmas = parse_num(inputptr);
    VMA **vma_list = malloc(sizeof(VMA*) * num_vmas);       // Create list of vmas
    proc->num_vmas = num_vmas;
    proc->pid = i;
    proc->page_table = pagetable;
    proc->vmalist = vma_list;

    for (int j=0; j<num_vmas; j++) {
        VMA *myvma = malloc(sizeof(VMA));                   // Create individual vma
        myvma = parse_vma(inputptr);
        vma_list[j] = myvma;                                // Add VMA to list
    }
    pl[i] = proc;                                           // Add process to list
}

printf("TESTING NOW:\n");
for (int i=0; i<num_ps; i++) {
    printf("PID: %d\n", pl[i]->pid);
    printf("Num VMAs: %d\n", pl[i]->num_vmas);
    for (int j=0; j<pl[i]->num_vmas; j++) {
        VMA *vma = pl[i]->vmalist[j];
        printf("in-mem: %d %d %d %d\n", vma->start_page, vma->end_page,
                vma->w_prctd, vma->f_mapped);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what is wrong. What is the input (show sample) and what is the expected output and what is the output you are getting (show sample).

Comment: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘struct VMA *’ using type ‘struct VMA’

Comment: Use the `&` operator to get the address of the VMA struct. As of right now, you are assigning a struct itself to the pointer.

Comment: `VMA **vma_list` is usually for declaring a 2-D array. The rest of your code is incomplete. `page_table` is not a member of `PROCESS`... See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: One thing I can see is that the definition of `PROCESS` must be *after* definition of `VMA`.